Refused to frame 'https://www.twitch.tv/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors
I want to put a broadcaster’s chat on Twitch on my own site, but I am getting an error. Is there anyone who can help solve this problem?
I was getting the same error when I wanted to add a live broadcast. I can solve this problem with JavaScript, but I cannot do the same solution for chat.
code :
<iframe
  id="chat_embed"
  src="https://www.twitch.tv/embed/buselinko/chat?parent=www.ayintaplogistic.com.tr"
  height="500"
  width="350">
</iframe>

error (console):
Refused to frame 'https://www.twitch.tv/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors ".
example web site :
https://etkinlik.ayintaplogistic.com.tr/yayinci.php 
I tried everything but couldn't solve the problem

if the page is https://etkinlik.ayintaplogistic.com.tr/yayinci.php then the parent is etkinlik.ayintaplogistic.com.tr but you stated www.ayintaplogistic.com.tr
So you would want
<iframe
  id="chat_embed"
  src="https://www.twitch.tv/embed/buselinko/chat?parent=etkinlik.ayintaplogistic.com.tr"
  height="500"
  width="350">
</iframe>

Or declare multiple
<iframe
  id="chat_embed"
  src="https://www.twitch.tv/embed/buselinko/chat?parent=etkinlik.ayintaplogistic.com.tr&parent=www.ayintaplogistic.com.tr"
  height="500"
  width="350">
</iframe>

On the assumption the subdomain page is a "test" and not the final destination.enter code here
